# Cannot implement stubbing in JUnit Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write Junit test cases using Mockito. Whenever I am trying to use stubbing i.e use when and returnThen, I am getting a compile time error that the when is unidentified for that class. The following is my JUnit snippet

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
registryIndexConfig = mock(RegistryIndexConfig.class);
when(registryIndexConfig.getIndexName()).thenReturn("Demogoblin");
}
```

I have imported the following classes, packages

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.testng.Assert;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner; 
import static org.mockito.Mockito.stub;
```

Please can someone point what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "I am getting a compile time error that the when is unidentified" That's pretty clear IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods `mock`, `when`, and many others are static methods in the `Mockito` class.

You must import them when using *unqualified* (with a *static import*):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Alternatively, you could import the `Mockito` class (like you did)

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
```

and use the methods *qualified*:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    registryIndexConfig = Mockito.mock(RegistryIndexConfig.class);
    Mockito.when(registryIndexConfig.getIndexName()).thenReturn("Demogoblin");
}
```

I prefer the static import way. It makes the test code look much cleaner.